# MS Access Database Not Maintaining with New Values

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I am working with MS Access DB and Visual Studio 2010. I have stored my DB in Bin\Debug\ Folder. When I insert some data into some table or update existing data, that work fine for 2-4 minutes. I have newer values in my Database. But when I close the  project and restart it, I get the old/previous values which were before insertion/updation.
Anyone can help what is the reason and how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: This is a mistake from you (I think), you have 2 database, 1 in your project and 1 in your bin folder

Comment: Yes i Have. But when I deleted the database from my project, it automatically deleted the file that was in Bin.

Comment: Just *don't* put the file there. `bin\Debug` is where the compiled files are stored and gets cleaned before *every* build.

Comment: Best way is to store your DB file in folder and change your connection string to read/write data from this folder.
So you need relative connection string

Comment: thanks all. It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to store your DB file in folder and change your connection string to read/write data from this folder.
So you need relative connection string

Comment: Dear @AneesQumarAbbasi you must to up vote correct answers an mark them as accepted answer

Comment: Yes . i Have. actually I am a just new in Stack overflow. I am accepting this right but votes are not getting increased

Comment: Yes know, I hope you be expert soon. If you need more info just let me know.

Answer (score 2):

"Bin\Debug" directory will be deleted anytime you do a "clean solution" (amongst various other reasons).  It is NOT the place to put your "i want to keep around" jet-database file.

Move your jet-database file to a subfolder like

> ".\DataStores\"

where the . is something like this:

> ".\MyProject.csproj"

So the jet-database file doesn't become victim of folder-cleansing.